# How to reset customer store credit in Magento2

Tags: magento2, store-credit

I added a store credit for a customer by mistake, how to revert the operation and reset customer store credit to 0.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: you can deduct an amount from the balance Or You can remove store credit for particular customer from the DB.

Comment: Hello Sir, I found the perfect way which is to update the balance using negative numbers. Thank you.